# EWS Move Email to Nested Folder

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

For some reason when I attempt to produce the ID for a nested folder, I don't get any results in the console. Here is my code:

```
                FolderView folderview = new FolderView(100);
                folderview.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
                folderview.PropertySet.Add(FolderSchema.DisplayName);
                folderview.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep;

                FindFoldersResults findFolderResults = service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Root, folderview);

                foreach(Folder f in findFolderResults)
                {
                    if(f.DisplayName == "DownloadedEmails")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(f.Id);
                    }
                }
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? Here is the Mailbox Structure if it helps:

[image: Mailbox Tree]

Answer (score 0):

You either need to do the search recursively - find the top folder (Inbox), then find its child folder (DownloadedEmails) etc. - or (in your particular case), simply open the Inbox folder (it is a well known folder), then find its subfolder (DownloadedEmails).

Comment: I thought starting at root would be the way to go, I'll play around with the idea of starting at inbox though. If you have any additional insight around this, or can show me how you would code it, it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In your case, all you need to do is replace `WellKnownFolderName.Root` with `WellKnownFolderName.Inbox`